# How does an LALR(1) grammar differentiate between a variable and a function call?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, lalr, shift-reduce-conflict

Given the following input:

```
int x = y;
```

and

```
int x = y();
```

Is there any way for an LALR(1) grammar to avoid a shift/reduce conflict? The shift/reduce conflict is deciding to reduce at `y` or continue to `(`.

(This is assuming that a variable name can be any set of alphanumeric characters, and function call is any set of alphanumeric characters following by parentheses.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a shift-reduce conflict unless it is possible for an identifier to be immediately followed by an `(` without being a function call. That's not normally the case, although in C-derived languages, there is the problem of differentiating cast expressions `(type)(value)` from parenthesized-function calls `(function)(argument)`.

If your grammar does not exhibit that particular C wierdness, then the LALR **(1)** grammar can decide between shifting and reducing based on the **(1)** token lookahead: if the lookahead token is a `(`, then it shifts the identifier; otherwise, it can reduce.

Comment: Thank you, I was under the wrong impression of what the 1 stood for.